# Delphi mathematical optimisation techniques including simplex or genetic algorithms, etc

Tags: delphi, pascal, genetic-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Just wondering whether anyone has recommendations for optimisation utilities for Delphi.
eg Simplex, Genetic algorithms etc...

Basically I need to optimise my overarching model as a complete black box function, with input variables like tilt angle or array size, within pre-determined boundaries. Output is usually a smooth curve, and usually with no false summits.

The old NR Pascal stuff is looking a bit dated (no functions as variables etc).

Many thanks, Brian

Comment: For genetic algorithms, check [RiverSoftAVG Genetic Algorithms Component Library](http://www.riversoftavg.com/genetic_algorithms.htm).

Comment: For numerical analysis, check http://www.dewresearch.com/

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, and I've been a professional software developer for almost 30 years. Maybe you could expand a little bit on what you're using, and cut the ambiguous buzzword coefficient down to a manageable level by explaining to all us Newbies what you're on about. Optimization? By that you mean performance optimization or curve fitting, or path-search optimization?

Comment: @WarrenP: that's an question of tools of numerical analysis, operational research and genetic algoritms. "Optimization" in this context (AFAIR, and it can be a little imprecise) is taking an operation or algoritm and apply numerical techniques over it to reach an certain object given a number of different variables involved.

Comment: I apologize upfront for any imprecision on that definition - last time I saw it was in university (more than 6 years ago)...

Comment: Sorry yes, Fabricio has it nailed, its about finding the input variable(s) of a maths function to find the min or max output value.

Comment: See [Linear and integer programming](http://vagul.tripod.com/index.html) or [Features of LP-optimizer](http://www.mynetcologne.de/~nc-weidenma/readme.htm)

Comment: Another link, [Decision Tree for Optimization Software](http://plato.la.asu.edu/guide.html).

Comment: You've got a smooth function with real domain and real co-domain? If so then you don't want simplex or GA.

Comment: Is this wikipedia article discussing the correct problem domain? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization

Comment: Or perhaps this wiki page?, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(mathematics)

Comment: I think that before you discuss specific software packages, you need to specify your problem better. Can you give more detail about what you mean by "complete black box function"? From what I understand, you're solving the problem (minimize f(x) s.t.  u <= x <= l). Do you know the function f(x), or is that a black box itself? If so, is the function evaluation noisy? Is the function evaluation expensive? How many function evaluations can you do?

Answer (score 1):

I found a program, written in Pascal, that simulates the Simplex method. It's a little old, but you may convert it into Delphi. You can find it

[here](http://jean-pierre.moreau.pagesperso-orange.fr/p_linear.html)

I hope it's of some use to you.

PS: If you have some cash to spend, try

[here](http://www.dewresearch.com/delphi)

Answer (score 0):

TSimplex Class
https://iie.fing.edu.uy/svn/SimSEE/src/rchlib/mat/usimplex.pas

For Mixed INteger Simplex
TMIPSimplex Class
https://iie.fing.edu.uy/svn/SimSEE/src/rchlib/mat/umipsimplex.pas

User: simsee_svn
Password: publico